# How I can make nfts fetching faster to show on frontend?

Tags: solidity, nft, ethers.js, react, polygon

I'm creating a marketplace where at the homepage I need to show up all the nuts at once on the homepage. Is there way I can make loading faster? It takes a lot of time to fetch data from the chain. I'm a frontend developer working with ethers and hardhat
by the way. Here is my function only returning one item at a time contracts are written by somebody else and he is not ready to change the code.

```
function createCollectible(
    string memory _tokenURI,
    string memory _TIER,
    string memory _BREED_COUNT,
    string memory _AGILITY,
    string memory _WEIGHT,
    string memory _STAMINA,
    string memory _HEALTH,
    string memory _LUCK
) public returns (uint256) {
    uint256 newTokenId = tokenCounter;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
    _setTokenURI(newTokenId, _tokenURI);
    NFTList[newTokenId] = dog(
        msg.sender,
        block.timestamp,
        _TIER,
        _BREED_COUNT,
        _AGILITY,
        _WEIGHT,
        _STAMINA,
        _HEALTH,
        _LUCK,
        _tokenURI
    );
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    emit CreateCollectible(
        msg.sender,
        block.timestamp,
        _TIER,
        _BREED_COUNT,
        _AGILITY,
        _WEIGHT,
        _STAMINA,
        _HEALTH,
        _LUCK,
        newTokenId
    );
    return newTokenId;
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you fetching the NTFs? If you want faster time probably you'll have to implement some sort of cache/indexer for the blockchain queries.

Comment: just figured it out just using nft aapis of moralis and building my own on subgraph

Answer (score 1):

who are coming after watching nadir dabit video I suppose them to check moralis nft apis they have lot m ore surprise you can easily fetch nfts
this is moralis docs how we connect moralis with react

```
https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/connect-the-sdk/connect-with-react
```

thats the link for nft api

```
https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/web3-api/nft-api
```

Returns an object with the NFT count for the specified contract and an NFT array belonging to the given address for the specified contract (asynchronous).
Options:
chain(optional): The blockchain to get data from. Valid values are listed on Supported Chains. Default value Eth.
format (optional): The format of the token id. Available values : decimal, hex. Default value : decimal.
cursor (optional): The next page of data to retrieve. Next page cursor value returned from each request.
limit(optional): limit (max 100).
address (optional): The owner of a given token (i.e. 0x1a2b3x...). If specified, the user attached to the query is ignored and the address will be used instead.
token_address(required): Address of the contract

```
import React from "react";
import { useMoralisWeb3Api } from "react-moralis";
​
const Web3Api = useMoralisWeb3Api();
​
const fetchNFTsForContract = async () => {
  const options = {
    chain: "polygon",
    address: "0x75e3e9c92162e62000425c98769965a76c2e387a",
    token_address: "0x2953399124F0cBB46d2CbACD8A89cF0599974963",
  };
  const polygonNFTs = await Web3Api.account.getNFTsForContract(options);
  console.log(polygonNFTs);
};
```

Comment: Please, can you expand your answer with an example. It isn't helpful as it is.

Comment: ok Im going to edit answer